# I am trying to find the Multiplicative Persistance of a number to number+1 in a loop. So what should i do to fix hte code?

Tags: python, loops, persistence

```
def per(n,steps=0):
    if len (str(n))==1:
        print(n)
        print "TOTAL STEPS" + str(steps)
        return "DONE"

    steps += 1
    digits = [int(i)for i in str(n)]
    result = 1
    for j in digits:
        result *= j
    print(result)
    per(result,steps)

count = 0
while True:
    print count
    count += 1
    str(wantedresult) == 12
    str(steps) >= 11
    if str(steps) == str(wantedresult)
        print str(n)
        break
```

I am noob.

I have another encoded and working code in my pockets(metaphorically) but not in a loop
so i wanted my results like this example in my other code is this
if my number is `277777788888899` it has an output of this

```
4996238671872
438939648
4478976
338688
27648
2688
768
336
54
20
0
0
TOTAL STEPS11
```

ummm you might need this
my error in the first code is

File "source_file.py", line 21
    if str(steps) == str(wantedresult)
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: What exactly is your question? There are some pretty obviuos mistakes in your while loop (e.g. `str(wantedresult) == 12`), is it about them?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to accomplish is to find the smallest number with a persistance of `wantedresult` by brute forcing all the number one by one? If so, here's something that does not differ too much from your first version:

```
def per(n,steps=0,display=False):
    # display the number at each iteration
    if display:
        print(n)
    if len(str(n)) > 1:
        steps += 1
        digits = [int(i)for i in str(n)]
        result = 1
        for j in digits:
            result *= j
        steps = per(result,steps,display)
    return steps


wantedresult = 6
persistance = 0
count = 0
while True:
    count += 1
    persistance = per(count)
    if persistance == wantedresult:
        print('The smallest number with a persistance of', wantedresult, 'is', count)
        per(count,display=True) # display the iterations for this number
        print('TOTAL STEPS', wantedresult)
        break
```

However it is suitable only for small persistance number and it might take a while if you want to find `277777788888899` with this approach.

BTW the syntax error you got is because you forgot the colon after the `if` statement.

Hope it helped.